# Avoiding type instability when slicing a tuple

Tags: julia

This question is an adapted version of what appeared [here](https://julialang.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/225542-helpdesk/topic/type.20stable.20tuple.20indexing) in the JuliaLang Zulip helpdesk.

---

Suppose I have a function that takes in a heterogeneously typed `Tuple` and will return a slice of that tuple where the slice indices may be statically inferred from only type information. How can I write my function in such a way that the output type is correctly inferred?

For example, suppose my function is

```
function f(t::Tuple, A::Array{T, N}) where {T, N}
    if T <: AbstractFloat
        imin = 1
    elseif T <: Integer
        imin = 2
    else
        imin = 3
    end
    imax = N+2    
    t[imin:imax]
end
```

we see that type inference only figures out that this produces a `Tuple`, not it's length or element types even though all the needed information is available at compile time?

```
julia> let t = (:a, "b", 2, 3.0, Val(1), 2+im), A = rand(Int, 3,3)
           Base.return_types(f, Tuple{typeof(t), typeof(A)})
       end
1-element Array{Any,1}:
 Tuple
```

How can I write `f` such that this works?

Answer (score 5):

The strategy I'd be most comfortable with (but maybe there's an easier way?) is to write a `@generated` function to manually ensure julia does the type level operations I want at compile time:

```
@generated function f2(t::Tuple, A::Array{T, N}) where {T, N}
    if T <: AbstractFloat
        imin = 1
    elseif T <: Integer
        imin = 2
    else
        imin = 3
    end
    imax = N+2
    out_expr = Expr(:tuple, (:(t[$i]) for i ∈ imin:imax)...)
end
```

The idea here is that in the generated function body, at compile time, we determine what `imin` and `imax` are, and then we manually build out an expression for our function body that reads `(t[imin], t[imin+1], ..., t[imax-1], t[imax])`.

For whatever reasons, julia is better able to reason about a sequence of `getindex(::Tuple, ::Int)` than it is about slicing a tuple, even with a statically known slice, so by manually building this expression, the compiler is able to do what we want:

```
julia> let t = (:a, "b", 2, 3.0, Val(1), 2+im), A = rand(Int, 3,3)
           Base.return_types(f2, Tuple{typeof(t), typeof(A)})
       end
1-element Array{Any,1}:
 Tuple{String,Int64,Float64}
```

Voila, the inferred output type is a`Tuple` of length 3 whose elements are statically known to be a `String`, and `Int` and `Float64`!

Answer (score 1):

You have to call some unexported functions, but you can do it without a `@generated` function like this:

```
julia> function f(t::Tuple, A::Array{T, N}) where {T, N}
           t = Base.IteratorsMD.split(t, Val(N+2))[1]
           if !(T<:AbstractFloat)
               t = Base.tail(t)
               if !(T<:Integer)
                   t = Base.tail(t)
               end
           end
           return t
       end
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> let t = (:a, "b", 2, 3.0, Val(1), 2+im), A = rand(Int, 3,3)
           Base.return_types(f, Tuple{typeof(t), typeof(A)})
       end
1-element Array{Any,1}:
 Tuple{String,Int64,Float64}
```

There are advantages in doing this with inferrable tuple manipulations: your code will likely compile faster and it's also [Revise](https://github.com/timholy/Revise.jl)-able.